# getting the error on adding DEFAULT values

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using this code to insert default values to my database and fetching that default value

```
public class DatabseHandlerTwo extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db_table";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String TABLENAME = "table_one";
public static final String KEYID = "_id";
public static final String DETAILS = "_details";
private static DatabseHandlerTwo mInstance = null;
Context context;

String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLENAME + "("+ KEYID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+ DETAILS + " TEXT DEFAULT 'RAM' )";

public DatabseHandlerTwo(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
}


public static DatabseHandlerTwo getInstance(Context ctx) {


    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new DatabseHandlerTwo(ctx.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mInstance;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLENAME);
}

public ArrayList<String> fetchDetails(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + DETAILS + " FROM " + TABLENAME,null);
    Log.e("value",cursor.toString());
    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                arrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DETAILS)));
                Log.e("value",cursor.getString(0));
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }catch (SQLiteException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return arrayList;
}
```

}

but i am getting this error:

> E/SQLiteLog: (10) Failed to do file read, got: 0, amt: 100, last Errno: 2

Comment: is it the only thing you are getting in Log? if you changed in query if table was already created in app then either reinstall app or upgrade the app version.

Comment: I have already reinstalled or upgraded the app version a lots of time but its not working.

Comment: query works without setting default value and not with default value, right?
print the query in Log and paste here

Comment: which line gives the error?

Comment: Are storage permissions mentioned in Menifest? Just clean your project and reinstall the app once

Comment: ok wait.. i am doing this..

Comment: Still getting the error @Usman

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:-

First of all switch line below code with changing in query line:

```
String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLENAME + " ("+ KEYID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+ DETAILS + " TEXT DEFAULT 'RAM')";
```

Also, change **fetchDetails** function like below:

```
public ArrayList<String> fetchDetails(){
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + DETAILS + " FROM " + TABLENAME,null);
//Log.e("value",cursor.toString());
try {
    if (cursor!=null && cursor.getCount() > 0 && cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            arrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DETAILS)));
            Log.e("value",cursor.getString(0));
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}catch (SQLiteException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    return arrayList;
}
```

And don't forget to uninstall previous app then run and install, because we change in query of creating table which executes in onCreate.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: actually i am getting that error when there is no data in database, but now i am inserting data using this:   public void insertItem(String item){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DETAILS,item);
        db.insert(TABLENAME,null,cv);
    }.  Now i am getting only that value which i am inserting using this method but not the DEFAULT value. Why ? How to get DEFAULT values.

Comment: @harshita Instead of just `db.insert()` I would preferably say everytime to use `db.insertorThrow(Table_Name, null, contentValues)` or `db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE)`.

Comment: @harshita Just comment this line `cv.put(DETAILS,item)` and try it.

Comment: @harshita Means if we set default then whenever SQL contentValues not get value at insert time, it will set default values to that. Without inserting data it will not set default value.

Comment: This means that we can never see the DEFAULT values added in CREATE TABLE query..?

Comment: @harshita Whenever we assign default in create_table query, it will add like in table structure. Means if don't provide value it will take default one at insert time.

Comment: I have commented what you have said and added these lines:    //cv.put(DETAILS,item);
        db.insertOrThrow(TABLENAME,null,cv); but getting this error now:  Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "null": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO table_one(null) VALUES (NULL)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148846/discussion-between-nitin-patel-and-harshita).

Comment: Hello sir, I have a new doubt, can i ask you ?.

Comment: Sir actually, i have a .pdf file in assets folder and i want to fetch all the content from it, how can i do this, any idea ?. I have searched a lot on net but can't find anything.

Comment: Actually the problem is that i want to show that content in a textview.

Comment: @harshita There is one library `iText7`. Using this library, AFAIK you can get data from pdf.

Comment: Thanks sir, I am getting all the content from my pdf using iText library but it is taking a very long time to fetch all content at once and my need is to fetch all content quickly at once (Fetching may take some time, but not so long).

Comment: Hello Nitin Sir... I have some doubt, can I ask you ?

Comment: Sir, I am successful in fetching content from pdf using iText library. This library is nice but its very slow. I am fetching single page at single time and on swiping a page it takes time in loading. Can't we convert pdf content into bitmap using iText ?

Comment: Hello Sir, I am working on NDK and stuck in a problem, can you help me plesase.

Comment: @harshita I haven't use NDK till now in application. But you can ask if I'll find answer, I will send you.

Answer (score 0):

You did miss out this `onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);` in onUpgrade

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLENAME);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}
```

So when you upgrade, no new Table is being created after drop.

Also edit:

```
mInstance = new DatabaseHandler(ctx.getApplicationContext());
```

to:

```
mInstance = new DatabaseHandler(ctx);
```

Comment: Is it possible you made some spell mistakes. Use ROOM for sqlite. It's an abstract layer over this. It's much preffered